# Driver compatibality issues in windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1-upgrade

I just want know whether Drivers are not yet designed to work with windows 8.1??? I'm having a Dell inspiron 3521 whereas finding very difficult to install drivers (AMD/ USB 3.0 host controller/Bluetooth) as it gives numerous bugs.

When I request drivers for windows 8.1 from my retail seller as a seRvice, they say they are not recommending windows 8.1 yet since drivers are not published & bugs may occur. DO I have to wait to advance myself for windows 8.1 until they recommend ??that's insane - Please support me on this ....many thanks

Comment: You can download drivers for your dell from the dell website. Try it.

Comment: I've downloaded above said drivers from dell site but what still unfixed is my AMD vga HD 8730M drive. as after installation it says load MMdriver has stopped working. I've clean up my PC by CC cleaner for complete uninstallation & reinstall from beginning but still these errors are prompting. then the Bluetooth driver. Bluetooth icon shows in task bar but not connecting as when I use windows 7. And next is that dell site does not gives the driver for USB port 3.0 whereas I have one 3.0 port. If you aware of a proper way please do post will be great help. Because I need to use windows 8.1

Comment: Many thanks it really worked out as i tried driver booster to find out what needed.

Comment: yes i will friend.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to vote up. still i have 8 only. I will vote once reach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some installers to install. They will do the installation neatly most of the time. Otherwise try a software named IOBit Driver Booster. It searches for out of date drivers in your system and allow you to download the updates and install them. Here is the link-

filehorse.com/download-driver-booster

First try Driver Booster.